# Can a username / password be passed as one string?

Tags: security, authentication, passwords, basic-authentication

In terms of mathematical guessability, are these equivalent?

```
username = user1
password = pass1
```

and

```
all_one_string = user1pass1
```

NB. This is a curiosity and not something I plan to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming that you pass them both in one string for validation purposes, there still needs to be a character in the middle to differentiate between the two strings.

For example, there is a similar implementation of this exact idea. **[Basic Authentication](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/basic-authentication/)**.

The idea is to pass both username and password in the same string, encode them in base64 and send them by an HTTP request Authorization header.

The string is usually passed as `username:password`.
After receiving the request, the server would then split the strings by the `:` character to retrieve the username and password.

Comment: So, apart from the extra character, they are equivalent in terms of security against brute force attacks?

Comment: As far as I know, Basic Authentication does not necessarily prevent brute force attacks. 
The easiest way to prevent brute force is probably to implement CAPTCHA or account locking techniques. Here's an article from OWASP about it: https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks